# xslt 3.0 xsl:evaluate example

Tags: dynamic, evaluate, xslt-3.0

For the following xml document:

```
<company>
   <employee>
      <name>John Andrews</name>
      <age>23</age>
      <salary>4000</salary>
      <division>Accounting</division>
   </employee>
</company>
```

I have the xsl like

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="company/employee/name"/>

    <xsl:variable name="test">
      <xsl:text>company/employee/name</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:evaluate xpath="$test"/>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can I use $test variable in xsl:evaluate in order to get the same result as in the:

```
<xsl:value-of select="company/employee/name"/>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: same result as in where...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the context item with e.g.

```
    <xsl:evaluate xpath="$test" context-item="."/>
```

Comment: can the  output of this 
 <xsl:evaluate xpath="$test" context-item="."/>
be starred in a variable like:
        <xsl:variable name="evluateTest">
            <xsl:value-of>
                <xsl:evaluate xpath="$test" context-item="."/>
            </xsl:value-of>
        </xsl:variable>

Comment: Have you tried that and run into a problem? What type do you want that variable to have, what kind of data value? Your path `company/employee/name` select a sequence of elements and the `xsl:evaluate` will return that sequence, if you want to bind that sequence to a variable use e.g. `<xsl:variable name="names" as="element(name)*"><xsl:evaluate xpath="$test" context-item="."/></xsl:variable>`. You might want to open a new question stating with more detail what you want to achieve.